# Initialize Oracle associative array in Sql Developer debugger

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, debugging

I have an associative array declaration that in a procedure that I am trying to debug, and I need to initialize the array in the debugger, but I can't seem to figure out the correct initialization string.

Here is the debugger block:

```
DECLARE
  I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY PKG_CLASSIFICATION_MATRIX.T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY :=    T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY('544679','512477');
  I_QUESTION_ID NUMBER;
  I_ANSWER_BOOLEAN NUMBER;
  O_UPDATE_INFO sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  --Modify the code to initialize the variable
  --I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY := NULL;

  --THESE ARE MY ATTEMPTS AT INITIALIZATION
  --I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY('1') := 544679; 
  --I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY('2') := 512477; 
  --I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY := PKG_CLASSIFICATION_MATRIX.T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY(544679,512477);

  I_QUESTION_ID := NULL;
  I_ANSWER_BOOLEAN := NULL;

  PKG_CLASSIFICATION_MATRIX.UPDATE_COLUMN(
     I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY => I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY,
     I_QUESTION_ID => I_QUESTION_ID,
     I_ANSWER_BOOLEAN => I_ANSWER_BOOLEAN,
     O_UPDATE_INFO => O_UPDATE_INFO
  );
 /* Legacy output: 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_UPDATE_INFO = ' || O_UPDATE_INFO);
 */ 
 :O_UPDATE_INFO := O_UPDATE_INFO; --<-- Cursor
 --rollback; 
END;
```

What I'm I doing wrong, or is it not possible to initialize the array in the fashion?

Here is the declaration of the array in the package spec:

```
TYPE T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
declaration of the array in the package spec:
TYPE T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

 debugger block:
I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY PKG_CLASSIFICATION_MATRIX.T_NUMBER_ASSOC_ARRAY;

begin
I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY  (1) := 'Value1';
I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY  (2) := 'Value2';
.
.
.
I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY  (n) := 'ValueN';
end;
```

Since your array is TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER, you cannot do I_COMPONENTS_ARRAY  ('1')